Remove some option in Product data meta box Wordpress
I am making a ecommerce website using Wordpress, Woocommerce and Astra theme.
In the "Add new" page there is a meta box "Product data" with 4 types of product: Simple Product, Grouped Product, Variable Product. I want it to show only the Variable option without other type.
My screen shot
I asked around and some told me to add code to functions.php, and I tried this:
function customize_product_data_meta_box() { // Remove Simple Product tab remove_meta_box( 'woocommerce-product-data-simple', 'product', 'normal' ); // Remove Grouped Product tab remove_meta_box( 'woocommerce-product-data-grouped', 'product', 'normal' ); // Remove External/Affiliate Product tab remove_meta_box( 'woocommerce-product-data-external', 'product', 'normal' ); } add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'customize_product_data_meta_box', 99 );
but it did not work and still show the default meta box
I want the Product data meta box to show only Variable Product and its field only whenever I log in with any admin account
